# Create 3 lines on one graph (named ranges)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I've been working on this for countless hours without being able to proceed. Any help with be greatly appreciated!

I'm trying to create macro that can loop through and create about 55 graphs. I'm having difficulties working with named ranged and I believe (until proven otherwise by the gurus here) that named ranges is the way to go.

I'm by no means done with this (i'll add a loop function) but for illustrative purposes the 3 ranges (and the 3 lines I want plotted on the same graph) looks as follows:

```
Set rng1 = Union(Cells(SA_Row, 11), Cells(SA_Row, 42), Cells(SA_Row, 72), Cells(SA_Row, 122))
Set rng2 = Union(Cells(SA_Row, 11), Cells(SA_Row, 43), Cells(SA_Row, 73), Cells(SA_Row, 123))
Set rng3 = Union(Cells(SA_Row, 11), Cells(SA_Row, 44), Cells(SA_Row, 74), Cells(SA_Row, 124))
```

Hence, all 3 lines will have the same starting value but then there is a lot of spacing between the different individual cells within the range. The reason why is that this represents targets for different years (example, 2020,2030,2040 etc.) So far I have mainly done formatting arguments, but I'll add a "Count = X to Y... Select case etc. That is a good way to go right? Anyhow, the code I have written so far looks like:

```
Set cht = Worksheets("Graphs").ChartObjects.Add(Top:=Graph_Position, Left:=910, Width:=160, Height:=75)

Set rng1 = Union(Cells(SA_Row, 11), Cells(SA_Row, 42), Cells(SA_Row, 72), Cells(SA_Row, 122))
Set rng2 = Union(Cells(SA_Row, 11), Cells(SA_Row, 43), Cells(SA_Row, 73), Cells(SA_Row, 123))
Set rng3 = Union(Cells(SA_Row, 11), Cells(SA_Row, 44), Cells(SA_Row, 74), Cells(SA_Row, 124))


With cht.Chart
    .ChartType = xlLineMarkers
    .HasLegend = False
    .HasAxis(xlCategory) = False
    .ChartArea.Border.LineStyle = xlNone
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).TickLabels.Font.Name = "VWAG TheSans"

        With .Axes(xlValue)
            .MaximumScale = 1
            .MajorUnit = 0.2
            .Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
            .MajorGridlines.Format.Line.Weight = 0.35
            .MajorGridlines.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(217, 217, 217)
            .TickLabels.Font.Size = 4
            .TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0%"

         End With

     'Set rngSource = Range(rng1, rng2, rng3)
     '.SetSourceData rngSource


   ' .SeriesCollection.NewSeries.Values = Range("rng1")
   ' .SeriesCollection.NewSeries.Values = Range("rng2")
   ' .SeriesCollection.NewSeries.Values = Range("rng3")



        With .FullSeriesCollection(1)
            .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(5, 204, 216)
            .MarkerStyle = 8
            .MarkerSize = 3
            .Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(5, 204, 216)
            .Format.Line.Weight = 1

        End With


        With .FullSeriesCollection(2)
            .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(192, 10, 0)
            .MarkerStyle = 8
            .MarkerSize = 3
            .Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(192, 10, 0)
            .Format.Line.Weight = 1

        End With

         With .FullSeriesCollection(3)
            .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(50, 200, 59)
            .MarkerStyle = 8
            .MarkerSize = 3
            .Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(50, 200, 59)
            .Format.Line.Weight = 1

        End With

End With
```

The `"'"` is just me playing around with different attempt. So far I have either no data on the graph, or just 1 line instead of 3 individual ones. Please help!

Comment: I would have considered a template : build one with all the data ranges set on one sheet and another sheet with all the charts using the relevant ranges from the other sheet. Then just use the macro to paste the relevant data into the ranges and saveas...

Answer (score 0):

I believe I may have solved it by the use of :

```
cht.Chart.SeriesCollection.Add Source:=rng1
cht.Chart.SeriesCollection.Add Source:=rng2
cht.Chart.SeriesCollection.Add Source:=rng3
```

What do you guys think?